# How do I use the Iterator trait to build generic APIs

Tags: collections, iterator, rust, traits

I may not see the forest for the trees but I wonder how do I actually design my methods to not work against hard collection types but against Iterators instead. Consider this method.

```
pub fn print_strings(strings: Vec<String>) {
    for val in strings.iter() {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

Obviously this falls short if I want to use that with an `HashSet` or `HashMap`.

So, I tried this:

```
use std::collections::*;

fn main () {
    let strings = vec!("Foo", "Bar");

    let mut more_strings = HashMap::new();
    more_strings.insert("foo", "bar");
    more_strings.insert("bar", "foo");

    print_strings(&strings.iter());
    print_strings(&more_strings.values())
}

fn print_strings(strings: &Iterator<Item=&str>) {
    for val in strings {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

**Playpen (also to view lengthy compiler error)**

http://is.gd/EYIK11

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick either. What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the error message. It tells you what is wrong with your implementation. You may want to review what the type of `Iterator::Item` is for the iterator you have.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea as it's pretty lengthy. You can click on the playpen link to see the whole compiler error output.

Comment: When you call `.iter()` on a  `Vec<T>`, you get an `Iterator<Item=&T>`. So when you call `.iter()` on a `Vec<&str>`, you get an `Iterator<Item=&&str>`, not a `Iterator<Item=&str>`. You should look at the `.cloned()` method for `Iterator`, it should help solve your problem.

Comment: Also, note that in order to iterate through an iterator, you must be able to mutate it (either own the iterator or have a mutable reference to it). So just having an immutable reference to it is sorta useless. I would recommend moving the iterator value into `print_strings` rather than passing it by reference. If you want to use trait objects for this, you can do that by using `Box`, but it might be easier to just make `print_strings` a generic function.

Comment: BTW here is a version of your code which works: http://is.gd/KUItXM

Comment: Awesome, I have to read up about thise `cloned` method. Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even better, you can do

```
fn print_strings<Iterable>(strings: Iterable)
    where Iterable: IntoIterator,
          Iterable::Item: AsRef<str>
{
    for val in strings {
        println!("{}", val.as_ref());
    }
}
```

<sup>(Kudos Shepmaster for the improvement.)</sup>

This means that you can call this with `&mut Iterator`s for dynamic dispatch *or* concrete iterator or collection types for static dispatch. Further, the iterator type can be anything that can be simply converted to `&str`, which includes but is not limited to `&str`, `&&str` and even `String`.

```
print_strings(&strings);
print_strings(strings.iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()));
print_strings(vec![&&&&"xyz"]);
print_strings(strings);
print_strings(more_strings.values());
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `.iter()` on a `Vec<T>`, you get an `Iterator<Item=&T>`. So when you call `.iter()` on a `Vec<&str>`, you get an `Iterator<Item=&&str>`, not a `Iterator<Item=&str>`. You should look at the `.cloned()` method for `Iterator`, it should help solve your problem.

Also, note that in order to iterate through an iterator, you must be able to mutate it (either own the iterator or have a mutable reference to it). So just having an immutable reference to it is sorta useless. I would recommend moving the iterator value into print_strings rather than passing it by reference. If you want to use trait objects for this, you can do that by using `Box`, but it might be easier to just make print_strings a generic function.

Answer (score 4):

[playpen](http://is.gd/XeEtWx)
So the first thing is that you're expecting `Iterator<Item=&str>`, but it's `Iterator<Item=&&str>` actually.
Then, you're trying to call `.iter()`, but `Iterator` doesn't have this method. 
You can simply remove `.iter()` call and receive (and send ofc) `&mut Iterator<...>` in order to get `for` loop working (`for` loop needs something, that implements `IntoIterator`, and `&mut Iterator` is that thing).
Add lifetimes and you're all set! :)
Also, I'm recommending to use static dispatch. You can see it in the example I provided.

Comment: Ok, that playpen clears it perfectly up. Regarding static dispatch, I was saving some keystrokes for the example :P